# Parse XML from URL in Python, wrong format

Tags: python, xml

I have several URL's with XML and everything was fine so far, but with next URL I get XML in a strange format. For getting XML from URL I use:

```
    req = Request("http://www.someUrlWithXml.com",
                  headers={'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
                        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
                        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
                        'Accept-Language': 'cs,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.6'})

    xml = urlopen(req).read()
```

When I print variable *xml* I get some weird format:

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xc7\xf6-Y\x00\xff\xed}{o\x1c9\x92 ...
```

In original XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 0 FT-->
<!-- 1 1st Half-->
<!-- 2 2nd Half-->
<!-- 3 1st Quarter-->
<!-- 4 2nd Quarter-->
<!-- 5 3rd Quarter-->
<!-- 6 4th Quarter-->
<!-- 7 Total Team Goals-->
<!-- 8 OutRight-->
<!-- 9 Match Props-->
<!-- 10 Total Booking In Match-->
<!-- 11 Red Cards-->
<!-- 12 First Booking-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xc7\xf6-Y\x00\xff\xed}{o\x1c9\x92 ...
```

The `b` at the front of the response indicates that it is a bytes object here and not a string. To decode it as a string, use `decode`:

```
xml.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: I tried to decode and now I get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Comment: @EdWood: Could you try xml.decode("utf-8", "ignore") and see if that gets you a usable result?

Comment: It's not usable, it gives me something like this: .Y}ko9P'ٝ"INw8e:N2`:-K][Id%*Vɗnj})fr:

Comment: @EdWood: Hmm, what about `xml.decode(xml.headers.get_content_charset())`?

Comment: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'headers'